# Train Linear SVM Model

Tags: matlab

I have a dataset with 50 predictor variables and two class labels (disease/normal).  When I run this code, I get the error message below.  Any ideas on how to correct this error?

```
[Mdl,FitInfo] = fitclinear(values(:,1:50),classes)
```

Error using classreg.learning.Linear.prepareDataCR (line 140)
X must be a numeric matrix.

Comment: What does a "numeric" matrix mean to you?  Hint: Think "numeric".

Comment: This works: [Mdl,FitInfo] = fitclinear(table2array(values(:,1:50)),table2cell(classes))

Comment: Outstanding. You figured it out.